# python dataframe replace and apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

When I try:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '').astype(float)
```

It would throw below error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-1 750.5'
```

But when I use:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(
    lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.').replace(' ', '')))
```

It would work. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are missing a second str.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is used [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for default substring replacement and [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) for not substring replacement, so is possible for match one or more whitespaces instead `' '` use `\s+` with:

```
#added second str.replace
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(',', '.').str.replace('\s+', '').astype(float)
```

---

```
#added regex=True for substring replacement in Series.replace 
df['Value'] = df['Value'].str.replace(',', '.').replace('\s+', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

---

```
#added regex=True for substring replacement in Series.replace with dictionary
df['Value'] = df['Value'].replace({',': '.', '\s+': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```